# Opening a zipped .tif file with rasterio

Tags: python, zip, raster, tiff, rasterio

Is there any way to open a `.tif` image within a `.zip` file with rasterio, without having to extract the `.tif` from the zip?

I have thousands of images which are nicely grouped in zip files and I want to analyse them with rasterio. Extracting all the images is going to take up quite a bit of storage so if possible I prefer not to...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) can open datasets contained within `.zip` files. Use the `zip+file` protocol, and separate the zip path from the path within the zip file with a `!`.

Example code:

```
import rasterio

path = 'zip+file:///path/to/file.zip!/folder/file.tif'
dataset = rasterio.open(path)
```

There's more information on the [Advanced Datasets documentation page](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasets.html#dataset-identifiers).